# Google Drive API Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=1.5.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, google-api, google-drive-api

This issue continues to be a problem.  I see several similar posts but they are all now a couple of years old.
I have referenced Google Apis via Nuget and now I am, quite frankly, in "Nuget hell".  First, a rant, why so many assemblies and references when you use Nuget, what is the purpose of the .NET Framework?  For example, why do I see a copy of System.IO DLL in my /bin folder?
I struggled for awhile just to get my website to run any of my code.  After I upgraded all of my assemblies to 4.0, and after I ran updates on my local .Net install running on Windows 8.1, I have my local dev website working again.
When I call any page on my site that calls the Google drive assembly code, I get this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Primitives,
Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its 
dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the
assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I've been round and round with the suggestions to map assemblies from this post:  [Google Drive SDK System.Net.Http.Primitives Version 1.5.0.0 instead of 2.1.10.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364922/google-drive-sdk-system-net-http-primitives-version-1-5-0-0-instead-of-2-1-10-0)
And either it doesn't work, or I do not have the correct assembly mappings.  I'm really at a loss.

I have compiled my Google Drive code and assembly separate of my web application assemblie(s).  My Google Drive code is working perfect and I only have an issue when I try to reference this project from my web application.

I can't find any additional tips here or from Google.  I am stuck.

Comment: I've apparently solved this after 3 days of trial and error, updating IIS, updating all of my assemblies, etc.  The final answer to getting my page to work was getting the correct assemblyBinding in my web.config.  However I am leaving this question open because what I still do not understand is who/why/what is referencing the 1.1.5.0 http primitive assembly.  This should get fixed.